# Iptables bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script, firewall, iptables

I currently have a script that adds rules to the firewall table based on a selection criterion between two files.

FILE 1 keys.txt

```
<string>
<string>
..
..
```

FILE 2 hellos.txt

```
<string> <ipaddress> <ipaddress>
<string> <ipaddress> <ipaddress>
..
..
```

My script matches a string from file 2 with a string from file 1. If a match exists, then it adds the firewall rule for the ipaddress following the string match.

The script is as follows -

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do

#Match a string from both the files and print the ipaddress to a file
word=$(awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' keys.txt hellos.txt | awk -v OFS=' ' '{ print $2, $3 }') >address.txt

#Remove duplicates for the ipaddress file
awk '!a[$0]++' address.txt > address_improved.txt

#Add firewall rule from new file.

filename=address_improved.txt
while read -r a b
do      
  "/sbin/iptables"  -I FORWARD 1 -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in enxa0cec80f92bd --physdev-out eno1 -s $a -d $b  -j ACCEPT

done < "$filename"
sleep 0.01

#Run while loop again because the files are changing constantly
done
```

How can I improve this script such that I do not add duplicate firewall rules everytime the while loop executes. I tried to add the -C (check) option but it does not work for me. I just get a bad rule output.

Comment: what creates keys.txt and hellos.txt?  Does the data come from syslog, another set of iptables rules? or what?  It **might** be possible to do away with most of this code.

Comment: Those two files come from an remote machine every few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Match a string from both the files and print the ipaddress to a file

Instead execute: (after following instructions)

```
ipset add allowed_hosts <ip> <ip>
```

(will not allow duplicates automatically)

Sets up ipset to be ready: (adjust maxelem to your liking)

```
ipset create allowed_hosts hash:net,net family inet hashsize 262144 maxelem 333000 counters comment
```

Your new rule:

```
 "/sbin/iptables" -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack -j ACCEPT --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 "/sbin/iptables" -I INPUT 2 -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in enxa0cec80f92bd --physdev-out eno1 -m set --match-set allowed_hosts src,dst -j ACCEPT
 "/sbin/iptables" -I INPUT 3 -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in enxa0cec80f92bd --physdev-out eno1 -m u32 --u32 "0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 0 & 0xFF000000=0x17000000" -j DROP
 "/sbin/iptables" -I FORWARD 1 -m conntrack -j ACCEPT --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 "/sbin/iptables" -I FORWARD 2 -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in enxa0cec80f92bd --physdev-out eno1 -m set --match-set allowed_hosts src,dst  -j ACCEPT
 "/sbin/iptables" -I FORWARD 3 -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in enxa0cec80f92bd --physdev-out eno1 -m u32 --u32 "0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 0 & 0xFF000000=0x17000000" -j DROP
```

Now your new loop:

```
while read -r a b
do      
  "/sbin/ipset" -! add allowed_hosts $a,$b

done < "$filename"
```

If you ever need to save the ipset table say for a reboot.

```
ipset save >ipset.txt
```

or

```
ipset save -f ipset.txt
```

bulk import, including autocreate from save.

```
ipset restore -f ipset.txt
```

It will be way more efficient as you don't need to keep changing iptables.

this single line might do away with everything but the loop

```
word=$(awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' keys.txt hellos.txt | awk -v OFS=' ' '{ print $2,$3 }') |xargs -n1 ipset -! add allowed_hosts
```

The xargs -n1 repeats the command for each line from stdin.  the -! hide the duplicate entries alert.  The output from the stdin is automatically appended so it isn't mentioned.

You will still need 1 iptables entry and the ipset mentioned above.

Comment: For some reason, I am not able to solve this error. I get the error 
`ipset v6.29: Syntax error: Second element is missing from 192.168.151.15.`

Comment: A simple command like 'sudo ipset -! add allowed_hosts 192.168.151.15 24.120.232.103' would give the same error

Comment: @AbhimanyuKhanna usually "second element" means you are missing something.  In this case they are comma delimited and not space delimited.  Whoops.  Also if your **print $2,$3** command does not emit a comma add one.  sudo ipset -! add allowed_hosts 192.168.151.15,24.120.232.103

Comment: spaces before or after the **,** (comma) will also give same error.

Comment: I was able to fix the formatting problem, but somehow the interaction leads to a whole set of other problems.

Comment: To summarize, here is what is happening - 

Initially I have a firewall rule that blocks ssl application data packets using the u32 module
`"/sbin/iptables" -I FORWARD 1 -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged --physdev-in enxa0cec80f92bd  --physdev-out eno1 -m u32 --u32   "0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 0 & 0xFF000000=0x17000000" -j DROP`

At a give point later, I get files containing the ipaddress for which I should allow all packets. I add the ip address on a "criterion" (if a string is matching etc - see the script in the question)

Your suggestion of using ipset helped improve the

Comment: performance penalty I was facing. I can now add the IP addresses efficiently without duplicates. However, somehow the interaction is not working. The block on the ssl application data packets from the initial rule is still in effect even after adding the rule in ipset. Would you know why is it leading to this.

Comment: My iptables rules look like this 
http://pastebin.com/akWzUJgE

and then I use the script above to add ip addresses.

Comment: First, for the easy part, you probably need to duplicate your rule in the input chain.  I modified my answer above to include the 6 iptables rules you need.

Comment: Did you do an **ipset save** to verify the contents of the set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50451/discussion-between-abhimanyu-khanna-and-cybernard).